# How to remove ' from the output

Tags: python

Code

```
for i in range(3):
    s = ('test',i)
    print (s)
```

```
('test', 0)
('test', 1)
('test', 2)`
```

is there any way to print like below

```
(test, 0)
(test, 1)
(test, 2)
```

Basically I need to print without `''`

Comment: The `''` is part of the fact its a string. Why do you need to print it without a string? Also. `print(s[0])` has no quotations because its printing the literal string.

Comment: Your code will result in calling the str function on a tuple (this is what print does), which in turn results in calling the repr function on every element of the tuple. The "repr" of a string, is a string with single quotes around it.  To get around this, you could write your own function to convert a tuple to a string that doesn't use repr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it important to retain the parentheses and comma? If not, simply add 1 `*` character to your print statement to [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the tuple

```py
for i in range(3):
    s = ('test',i)
    print(*s)
```

output:

```
test 0
test 1
test 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to print the result as a formatted string, including your `()`

```
for i in range(3):
    s = ('test',i)
    print (f"({s[0]}, {s[1]})")

#(test, 0)
#(test, 1)
#(test, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(3):
    s = ('test',i)
    print (s[0], s[1])
```

This output's

```
test 0
test 1
test 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below,

```
for i in range(3):
    print ('(test, {})'.format(i))
```

Output

```
(test, 0)
(test, 1)
(test, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this code remove the single quotes

```
 for i in range(3):
        s = ('test',i)
        print ('('+str(s[0])+','+str(s[1])+')')
```